# $\partial_xU(x,t)=1/2[U(x,t)]^2-aU(x,t)+b$ Using Separation of variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that we have the following partial differential equation:

$\partial_xU(x,t)=1/2[U(x,t)]^2-aU(x,t)+b$.

As a hint, they said in the exercise, use seperation variables first, but I'm stuck, because first of all the equation is nonlinear.

Answer (score 0):

For each fixed $t$ you have for $u(x)=U(x,t)$, $u(0)=u_0(t)=U(0,t)$ the ODE
$$
u'=\frac12u^2-au+b,~~u(0)=u_0(t)
$$
which is separable as
$$
\int_{u_0(t)}^{u(x)}\frac{dy}{\frac12y^2-ay+b}=x.
$$